# Visual Studio change display of summaries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In C# you can write Summaries:

```
/// <summary>
/// My Text
/// </summary>
```

If you collapse that, you get that:

```
/// <summary> ...
```

When you write summaries like that:

```
/// <summary>My Text
/// </summary>
```

You get that:

```
/// <summary>My Text ...
```

First doesn't show any information when collapsed, second one is a little bit annoying because of the long highlighted lines in the code.

Is it possible to change the settings that you can switch between both *without* changing the Summary?

Comment: What? Just don't have the summary on the same line as the `<summary>` delcaration. Or just find and replace `<summary>` with itself plus a line break, triple slash and a space.

Comment: You are already switching between both by typing them differently. What more do you want?

Comment: Your only complaint can be resolved by simply not putting the summary on the same line as the `<summary>` declaration. AFAIK there is no option that does what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension for VS: [HideShow Comments](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03141ea7-c35e-4533-b05b-9e60545e93eb). There you can hide the comments in a little symbol.

Now I can write comments like that:

```
///<summary>My Text
///</summary>
```

Vanilla result:

```
///<summary>My Text...
```

And with HideShow its only a little symbol. Satisfy both whishes :)